# SQLite queries taking a long time - Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, sqlite

I have a ionic angular application and I am using SQLite as the local database.

I have the following query:

```
const statement = '  SELECT fl.*, ai.*, fl.uuid as fluuid ' +
  '(SELECT aName FROM world WHERE world.uuid = fl.daUUID) as depName, ' +
  '(SELECT country FROM world WHERE world.uuid = fl.daUUID) as depCountry, ' +
  '  FROM fl, ai WHERE fl.userUUID= ? AND ai.uuid=fl.aiUUID  ORDER BY Date ASC';
```

I have the following create statements for then the app starts:

table fl

```
           `create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  fl
    (
        ID                   int                                 primary key,
        daUUID               text                                null,
        aaUUID               text                                null,
        aiUUID               text                                null,
        uuid                 text                                null,
        userUUID             text                                null,
        updateTimeStamp      DATETIME not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
    create index IF NOT EXISTS ix1Fl1
        on fl (userUUID, aiUUID, uuid);
    create index IF NOT EXISTS ix1Fl2
        on fl (daUUID, aaUUID);
        `
```

table ai

```
           `create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  ai
    (
        aiID                  int                                 primary key,
        uuid                  TEXT                                null,
        userUUID              TEXT                                null,
        updateTimeStamp       DATETIME not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    
    );
    create index IF NOT EXISTS ix1Ai1 on ai (uuid, userUUID);
          );`
```

table world

```
    `
    create table IF NOT EXISTS world
    (
        aiID            int                                 primary key,
        uuid            text                                null,
        userUUID        text                                null,
        updateTimeStamp timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );create index IF NOT EXISTS ix1world1
        on world (uuid, userUUID);`
```

as seen I have added the index but (just like my live db) but the query runs slow,

but if I remove this from the query

```
  '(SELECT aName FROM world WHERE world.uuid = fl.daUUID) as depName, ' +
  '(SELECT country FROM world WHERE world.uuid = fl.daUUID) as depCountry, ' +
```

the query runs fast again.

Wondering what the solution is for this? (The same concept works for my live db very fast)

(NOTE: I have cut the create statement down as they would be too long to post)

Thank you

Comment: There are no aName and country columns in the table world and there is no column Date in any of the 3 tables. So I guess this is not your actual code.

Comment: @forpas read the note in the question, I removed things not relevant. I know the dates etc are not going to make a difference as  opposed to the actual joining and indexing like the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the two correlated subqueries with one join :

```
SELECT fl.*, ai.*, fl.uuid as fluuid,
world.aName AS depName,
world.country as depCountry
FROM fl, ai
JOIN world ON world.uuid = fl.daUUID
WHERE fl.userUUID= ? AND ai.uuid = fl.aiUUID
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

or even :

```
SELECT fl.*, ai.*, fl.uuid as fluuid,
world.aName AS depName,
world.country as depCountry
FROM fl
JOIN ai ON ai.uuid = fl.aiUUID
JOIN world on world.uuid = fl.daUUID
WHERE fl.userUUID = ?
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, this has significantly increased speed :)